# C randomize with percents influence

Tags: c, random

Here's my ramdomize code:

```
int monstername;
monstername = rand() % 3;
```

but I want 0 with 70% of output 1 with 20% 2 with 10% how I can do this with C?

Comment: There are already several good answers below, but you should really consider reading up on modulo bias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int monstername;
int random_var = rand() % 10;

if(random_var < 7) {
    // 0-70%
    monstername = 0;
}
else if(random_var < 9) {
    // 70-90% here
    monstername = 1;
}
else {
    // 90-100% here
    monstername = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
int monstername;
int rn = rand();

if (rn < 0.7*RAND_MAX)
    monstername = 0;
else if (rn < 0.9*RAND_MAX)
    monstername = 1;
else
    monstername = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't care about [modulo bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator), you want something like:

```
int monstername;
int r = rand() % 10;

if (r < 7)
    monstername = 0;
else if (r < 9)
    monstername = 1;
else
    monstername = 2;
```

If you *do* care about modulo bias, look into [`arc4random_uniform(3)`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3/arc4random_uniform/) instead of `rand(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int weighted[10] = {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0};
monstername = weighted[rnd() % 10];
```